# @User.Identity.Name is null on IIS on the _layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have web applicaiton with .net core 2.1. I have the below code in _layout.cshtml.  It displays domain\name on my pc. It comes `enter code here`as null pn IIS.

```
<p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">@User.Identity.Name</p>
```

Here is a
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,

Comment: is impersonation turned on?

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185514/user-identity-name-is-null-in-asp-net-core-2-x-web-application-using-windows-aut) discussed a similar issue, you can check if the issue is caused by outdated ASP.Net Core Module installed.